# Adding/removing connection to more than one groups

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, signalr, signalr-hub

I use SignalR for Web chat application and I met with next problem. I have one connection and two groups. I try to add some connection to both groups and to my collection of connectionId's:

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    ...

    Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "Group1");
    Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "Group2");
    connections.add(Context.ConnectionId, "online");

    ...
    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

My opinion it is not thread-safe function because inerruption of current thread can happen between these three operaions. I need that information was synchronized in SignalR groups and my collections of ConnectionId's. I mean there are no situation when "Group1" send message to the ConnectionId and "Group2" did not make it. And so on. How can I decide this problem?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you are trying to do and what went wrong?

Comment: @LumpN, I want that these three operations were executed without interruptions of current thread. Is it possible?